# How to correctly float lists

Tags: html, css

I'm having a hard time with floats. I am trying to float the list on the header and footer to the right and keep the image on the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/KYdnJ/21/

When I add in the floats the layout goes all screwy. This is the CSS which is relevant:

```
#header {
    line-height: 50px;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
    padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#header li { 
    font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
    background-color: #D3D3D3; 
    display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold; 
    line-height: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px; 
    font-size: 12px;
    float: right;
}
#header img {
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
}
```

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Comment: It is not correct to float lists. So the answer is **not**. Just use `position` and `display`

Comment: @Bondye Why is it not correct to float (unordered) lists?  The W3C specification says a float can be applied to any element.  Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-float.  Did you mean list item?

Comment: @Bondye Why is it not correct ? Any resource ?

Comment: Float is created for images, to wrap text around etc. But most designers misunderstand float and use it for layout.. It is bad practice... http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: @Bondye I skimmed through and didn't see where it says float was created only for images.  I also don't see how it's bad practice.  I'd say it's bad practice using the position and display.  It prevents your page from flowing and being responsive on different resolutions and sizes, from mobile devices to 50" TV's as monitors.  Even if that website did say something to reinforce your statement, it's some magazine, not a decent source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with floating the individual `li` is that they end up floating *within* the `ul`, which itself remains left-aligned.  Rather than floating the individual `li` elements, you can float the whole `ul`.  At least in the jsFiddle, it's also necessary to bulk up the `#main` section, lest the footer and header collide:

```
ul {position:relative;float:right;}
#main {height:200px;width:100%;clear:both;}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KYdnJ/23/), with the floats on the `li` removed and the above CSS added.

Comment: Thank you for the help but that gives me this, which still doesn't seem quite right. The lists are on the left and on the line below: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/KYdnJ/24/

Comment: @Jimmy Oops, I see the problem!  My CSS should read `ul` rather than `#ul`.  I had it right in my jsFiddle but wrong in my posted code.  It's now been changed in the answer - switching from `#ul` to `ul` should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, just remove all float:right that you have.

Comment: Please provide a more specific answer as to why you think removing the floats would help solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try with this. Add float:right in

> **#header ul**

instead of

> **#header li**

and make sure to clear floats. Add one div with class clear

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
   <img src="test.jpg"/>
   <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Post</a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #E8E8E8;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#header ul { 
  font-family: arial, sans-serif; 
  background-color: #D3D3D3; 
  display: inline-block; 
  font-weight: bold; 
  line-height: 28px; 
  padding: 0px 9px 0px 9px; 
  font-size: 12px;
  float: right;
}
#header img {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
}
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `overflow:hidden` to the header and footer divs

http://jsfiddle.net/XQLkR/